# How can I disable guest browsing mode in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

As of Chrome 59 the check box to not enable guest browsing mode is gone. Many parental control systems depend on this. Supervised Chrome accounts can no longer be created. Google's answer is Family Link, but this only works on mobile devices, not desktop. So how do you disable guest browsing in today's Chrome?

Comment: Here's the same question for Edge: https://superuser.com/q/1667427/90668

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completely disabling in Windows the guest mode in Chrome:

- Start the Command Prompt application using Run as Administrator
- Copy and paste the following commands into the Command Prompt and press
  <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

  ```
    REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /v BrowserGuestModeEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
    REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /v BrowserAddPersonEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
  ```
- Restart Chrome.

The information about the flags of
[BrowserGuestModeEnabled](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#BrowserGuestModeEnabled)
and
[BrowserAddPersonEnabled](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#BrowserAddPersonEnabled)
comes from
[The Chromium Projects - Policy List](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3):

> **BrowserGuestModeEnabled**
>
> Enable guest mode in browser
>
> **BrowserAddPersonEnabled**
>
> Enable add person in user manager

Under **Mac/Linux** these are preference names.
Their values are:
`0` (Windows), `false` (Linux), `<false />` (Mac).

Comment: For Microsoft Edge on Windows, the registry path is in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`, and the keys are `BrowserGuestModeEnabled` and `BrowserAddProfileEnabled` (notice that the word "Profile" is used, to "Person").

Answer (score 2):

After an hour of searching I found a Youtube video with an answer that currently works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_7WW4C16z4

In short, you make one registry key, log out, and log back in. Here is the contents of a .reg file that you can create to do this for you:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
>   "BrowserGuestModeEnabled"=dword:00000000

Comment: This worked for me! Note that this only works on Windows, presumably there are other solutions on other operating systems.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=BrowserGuestModeEnabled

Answer (score 0):

## On Linux:

You need to set up two policies. Follow these instructions for Google Chrome (the paths are different for Chromium):

1. Create these directories if they do not exist already:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/opt/chrome/policies
   sudo mkdir /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
   sudo mkdir /etc/opt/chrome/policies/recommended
   ```
2. Create a JSON file in the `managed` directory, named whatever you want:

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/test_policy.json
   ```
3. Modify that file to contain this JSON:

   ```
   {
     "BrowserGuestModeEnabled": false,
     "BrowserAddPersonEnabled": false
   }
   ```
4. Restart Chrome.

For Chromium, the instructions are the same, but the parent path is `/etc/chromium` instead of `/etc/opt/chrome/`.

#### References:

- [Linux Quick Start for setting up a managed instance of Google Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start)
- [Documentation for `BrowserGuestModeEnabled`](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#BrowserGuestModeEnabled)
- [Documentation for `BrowserAddPersonEnabled`](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#BrowserAddPersonEnabled)