# How do I disable guest mode and "Add new person" in Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge allows you to create new profiles, and to launch guest mode. However, I would like to disable both of these functionalities.

How can I do this?

Comment: Here's the same question for Chrome: https://superuser.com/q/1442330/90668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, open the Registry Editor by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then typing `regedit`, then clicking OK.

Navigate with the Registry Editor to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`. If that folder is not already there, create it.

Add these two DWORD (32-bit) Value entries:

- `BrowserAddProfileEnabled`, and set the value to 0.
- `BrowserGuestModeEnabled`, and set the value to 0.